# Is there any use case which keeps Early-Suspend for a long time?

Tags: android

I know that in music playback, an Android device can keep early-suspend state for a long time (LCD off but not going down to suspend, since drivers are still working) but:

- is there any other use case keeping the state for a long time? (perhaps like downloading data in background?)
- if so, could you suggest any specific apk doing that?

I am curious about this in terms of power consumption of the device.
If there are quite a few cases, the power consumption should be improved specifically in that state.

Answer (score 0):

I am also curious to know this. Even there are no active application running in background, there are one or the other wake locks on hold preventing SUSPEND.... EARLY SUSPEND will stay for ever i guess